# Removing a row from the Database through ListView (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, database, listview

```
<ListView Height="330" VerticalAlignment="Top"   Name="Customers" Grid.Row="1" >
    <ListView.View>
                <GridView >
                    <GridViewColumn Header="FirstName" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="LastName" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Email" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Email}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Phone" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Phone}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I use a service for the Delete function. I need to send a customer in order to delete it from the table. I want to add a column for each row that deletes that row from my DB.
I have no idea how to do it.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Add a column containing Delete buttons for every row :

```
<GridViewColumn>
     <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="Delete" Click="DeleteButton_Click"/>
         </DataTemplate>
     </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Code :

```
    private void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Customer rowEntity = ((Button)e.OriginalSource).DataContext as Customer;
        /* Delete code ... */
    }
```